# Java : Play List of Tracks In Android MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a list of tracks using MediaPlayer in Android Studio. It is a music application and there are play, pause and next buttons. I am able to play one song on loop using media player but I am just unable to figure out how to go to the next track using the next button.

Would love if someone could help me out with the Java code for playing a list of tracks in Android Studio using media player.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add your code snippet and point out where exactly the problem arises, this is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Class for reading MP3 files from SDcard

> This class will read all the files from device sdcard and filters the
>   files which are having `.mp3` extension.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

## Retriving the songs playlist

```
SongsManager songManager;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
playList = songManager.getPlayList();
```

> the `playList` object can be used to play individual songs, using a
>   `ListView` or etc

```
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Before that get a through understanding of [Android Media Player API docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

For more detailed explanation use this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Hope it helps :)